# ajax call returns value but variable is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a weather forecast from [here](http://openweathermap.org/). This is working fine and I get my value. If I do a normal ajax call it is working fine.

But:

```
function Weather() {
    var self = this,
        weatherUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=',
        value = null;

    function getWeatherForCity(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: weatherUrl + id,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                value = data;
            }
        });
    }

    self.getWeatherForCity = function (id) {
        var cast = value;
        console.log(cast);
        return cast;

    };
}
```

The call:

```
        weather = new Weather();

        console.log(weather.getWeatherForCity('2878234'));
```

If I debug through those functions, I get the good result inside of the success callback function, but cast variable is null, like it was never touched?

Could someone explain that to me?

Comment: Let's just start with the fact that `async: false` is very bad and deprecated thing.

Comment: well, i know but this is not really the answer.

Comment: The problem is that you never actually call `getWeatherForCity()`. Hence the result.

Comment: `getWeatherForCity` is a private function and it is not call when you do `weather.getWeatherForCity('2878234')`

Comment: how could that be a private function? its on the object

Comment: @Ipad because you declared it (`function getWeatherForCity(id) { ... }`) as private function.

Comment: thank you regent, your are absolutely right.! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**. You problem is that you never call local `getWeatherForCity` function. So it never changes the `value` variable. This should fix it:

```
self.getWeatherForCity = function (id) {
    getWeatherForCity(id);
    return value;
};
```

**Better approach**. Looks like you are aware that using `async: false` is not the ideal solution. In this case I will suggest you better option.

```
function Weather() {

    var self = this,
        weatherUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=';

    function getWeatherForCity(id) {
        return $.get(weatherUrl + id);
    }

    self.getWeatherForCity = function (id) {
        return getWeatherForCity(id);
    };
}

var weather = new Weather();
weather.getWeatherForCity('2878234').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Using asynchronous code makes UI non-freezing during request. And usage of promises makes code cleaner and more comprehensive.

Comment: thanks, yes i know it but i tried a little bit around! Thanks for your help. i will delete it immediatly

Comment: i think its better to remove the private function itself and do the things that you have done in method. why to create an unnecessary private function..

Comment: @bipen Maybe you are right. It depends on some factors. OP may want to some additional processings. But if not, then yes it can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different `getWeatherForCity()` functions - one is a method, and one is a private function (inside the closure). You never call the private function, that actually does the work.

```
function Weather() {
    var self = this,
        weatherUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=',
        value = null;

    function getWeatherForCity(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: weatherUrl + id,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                value = data;
            }
        });
    }

    self.getWeatherForCity = function (id) {
        getWeatherForCity(id); // here
        var cast = value;
        console.log(cast);
        return cast;

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the $.when method, which waits for an Ajax call to complete before proceeding:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

You'd use it like this:

```
$.when(getWeatherForCity([pass the parameter here])).done(function(){
    // do stuff here after the method is finished
});
```

You would also need to use a return for your Ajax function like this:

```
return $.ajax({
        url: weatherUrl + id,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            value = data;
        }
    });
```